# Add more than one condition to my equation

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, physics, conditional

I have the following code to solve for a bunch of n, m e U, but I need different conditions for n=0 and m=n, already explicit in my code, but I don't know how to make it work. I know I have to make it conditional, but I can't make it right.

```
Clear[n, m, u, w, bint, beta, g, dg, bb, dbb, gama, dgama, fvc, defvc]
{beta[0] = 2, beta[Infinity] = 1}

{2, 1}

beta

bint[u_] = If[u != 0,
NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, x] BesselJ[1, x]/(x + x Exp[u 
      x/2]), {x, 0, Infinity}]]
beta[u_] = x /. FindRoot[(x/Pi) Sin[Pi/x] == 2 bint[u], {x, 1, 0, 2}]


efvc 

bb[n_, m_, u_] = beta[u]^alpha[n, m, u]

alpha[n_, m_, u_] = ((n^2 - m^2)/n^(15/8))^CubeRoot[u]

gamma[n_, m_, u_] = 2 Exp[(Sqrt[u])/(1 - (m/n)^(3/2))]

efvc[n_, m_, 
u_] = -(((2 bb[n, m, u])/Pi)) (Sin[(Pi*n)/(bb[n, m, u])]) (Cos[(Pi*m)/
 gamma[n, m, u]])

efvc[n_, m_, u_] = If[m = n, -(2/Pi)*Sin (Pi*n)]
efvc[n_, m_, u_] = If[n = 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few preliminary things:

1. You should use `:=` ([`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)) rather than `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) in function definitions
2. `=` is always an assignment -- `==` ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) is a comparison.

Now for the main part of the question.  You can do:

```
ClearAll[efvc]
efvc[n_, m_, u_] /; n == 0 := 0
efvc[n_, m_, u_] /; n == m := -(2/Pi)*Sin [Pi*n]
efvc[n_, m_, 
  u_] := -(((2 bb[n, m, u])/
      Pi)) (Sin[(Pi*n)/(bb[n, m, u])]) (Cos[(Pi*m)/gamma[n, m, u]])
```

We've used `/;` ([`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html)) to differentiate between the definitions.  When we give multiple definitions like this, Mathematica will search our expressions for pieces that match the left hand side of one of these definitions, replacing the first one it finds with the right hand side of the corresponding definitions.  When we add a condition, we make sure that e.g. `efvc[1,2,u]` doesn't match `efvc[n_, m_, u_] /; n == 0`.

Comment: Thanks you! Worked flawlessly. So, if I need to add any other condition, I should follow the same steps?

Comment: Yes -- your condition can be any logical relation (think: anything that can form the condition of an if statement), so you can use [logical relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalAndLogicalOperators.html) to make arbitrarily complicated conditions.  There are also some more advanced uses of `Condition` -- see the docs for `Condition` and this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html), among others.